# Send email on .net core application hosted on docker not work

Tags: .net, docker, smtpclient

"I have a problem in my .NET Core application. I implemented a service to send emails using System.Net.Mail.

It works well when I run it in the localhost environment.

However, when I deploy it to a Docker host, I get a timeout. I am using the same host configuration in both environments, but in Docker, I encounter a timeout issue.

The application does not return an error, and it does not reach the catch statement."

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message, EmailConfigDto config)
{
    try
    {
      

        using SmtpClient smtpClient = new(config.StmpHost);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(config.StmpUsername, config.StmpPassword);

    
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
        
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);

    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly the `config.StmpHost` is looking? Are you sure that `config.StmpHost` is reachable from the container? Are you using Linux containers?

Comment: Yes , Linux, container .

Comment: I will log the config.StmpHost for check

Comment: Also JIC `SmtpClient` is `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` ?

Comment: Yes System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Comment: I logged config.StmpHost and teh config are ok

Comment: Have you checked that the address is available from.the docker? What is the host by the way? Also try using https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit instead of build-in library

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that my host has a policy that blocks emails sent by foreign servers. Since I am using a foreign server on AWS, my host blocked the emails. I followed the host's documentation to avoid this block.

https://king.host/wiki/artigo/como-ativar-o-smtp-internacional/